# SSRS MailTo Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a textbox with the following expression- ="MailTo:example@gmail.com".

I have tried with and without the quotes. With the quotes, I just get the actual text, which is MailTo:example@gmail.com. Without the quotes, I receive an error about using a colon.

What I want to do is hyperlink the email address so that it can be clicked on in the report, and have outlook open. How can I achieve this?

Apparently, the above does not describe my problem enough...let's see if this works...

Answer (score 2):

Right click the textbox and go to `Textbox properties`, in the Action tab select `Go to URL` and use the expression you need:

```
 ="mailTo:example@gmail.com"
```

Also if you set the Place Holder `Markup Type` property to HTML you can use an expression like this:

```
="<a href=" & CHR(34) & 
"mailto:alejandro.zuleta@example.com" & Chr(34) &
">send mail to alejandro</a>"
```

Which results in a hyperlink to the specified mail address that executes your default E-Mail client to send the mail.

Let me know if this helps.